# Is there any SDK or Service API which can be used to scan malware for audio file for Mobile Applications?

Tags: android, ios, file, security, upload

In my Mobile app, user can upload any audio file from it's memory. I am concerned about security as
any malware can be hidden in the audio file or malware itself can be uploaded. So is there any SDK or Service, Rest API (Paid/Free) which can be used for scanning audio files?

Comment: Have a look at [Virus Total](https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002100149-API) : I found it searching for : «scan a file for malware» on Google